i want resource name defined by the user in aws irrespective of resource type
So, basically i want the name defined by the user while creating of a resource in aws.
But there are different methods, and different functions for different resources i.e. for ec2 its different, for efs its different etc.
I have different attributes like resourceid etc, but im not able to get this particular attribute.
I studied the boto3 documentation but didn't find a particular method which can solve my problem.
I want a general method which fetches me the name of the resource irrespective of the resource type.

If you want to associate a user with resources, it is probably better to use a tag rather than a name. However, you will also find that tagging methods differ by AWS service.

Names themselves are not treated consistently in AWS.  Some resources (eg VPC, EC2) they're just a tag.  Other resources (S3 bucket, SQS Queue) the name is not a tag but a primary identifier, part of the ARN that needs to be unique and is immutable for the life of the resource.

like, i want important information ; let's say for ec2 i want the instance type for s3 -storage etc. I'm looking for an API which fetches me the important details of all my resources which i have initiated.
